# Can a nested for loop in C recursively increase in depth times a user given integer?

Tags: c

I would like to avoid a nested for loop since it should recursively increase in depth by a user given integer.

So if the user input 3 it should be nested like the example below.. if the user input 6 there should be three more loops inside!?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // int depth_lvl = 3
    char n[] = {'a','b','c'};
    int i,j,y;
    int x = sizeof(n);

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++)// <---- LEVEL 1
    {
        printf("%c\n",n[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++)// <---- LEVEL 2
        {
            printf("%c%c\n",n[i],n[j]);
            for(y = 0; y < x; y++) // <---- LEVEL 3
            {
                printf("%c%c%c\n",n[i],n[j],n[y]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `for` loops are not recursive. There is no recursion in the code shown, your question is unclear.

Comment: This cannot be done with nested for loops: the depth of the loop nest is fixed at compile time.  But your intuition is correct: this can be done using recursion.  You will be writing a function with _one_ for loop inside, that calls itself recursively.  That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Please focus first on the termination condition, at the start of the recursive function, that prevents the recursion from running away and causing stack break.

Comment: @Olaf sry if my question wasn't clear enough I tried to give an example how the recursive function should work out rather than post my buggy function itself..

Comment: @zwol yeah thank you for confirming that it is supposed to work this way.. I wasn't sure anymore.. I try to write a function like this in the moment..

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for mention the base condition.. I implemented it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like that what you are looking for?
The solution uses recursion together with an intermediate result string at each level, with which each state of the current level is carried over to the next deeper level.

```
#define MAX_DEPTH 6

void printRecursive(char n[], int x, int curDepth, char* result)
{
    // note: x is supposed to be sizeof(n).

    if (x > MAX_DEPTH)  // prohibit overflow of intermediateResult
        x = MAX_DEPTH;

    if (curDepth < x) {
        char intermediateResult[MAX_DEPTH+1];
        if (result)
            strcpy(intermediateResult,result);
        else
            strcpy(intermediateResult, "");

        for (int i=0;i<x;i++) {
            intermediateResult[curDepth] = n[i];
            intermediateResult[curDepth+1] = '\0';
            printRecursive(n,x,curDepth+1,intermediateResult);
        }
    }
    if (curDepth > 0)
        printf("%s\n", result);
}

int main(void)
{
    char n[] = {'a','b','c', 'd'};
    int x = sizeof(n);
    printRecursive(n, x, 0, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the max depth is not a problem but I also wonder about depth 5 & 6?

Comment: I thought if I would have a level 6 depth nested for loop I would get  a string with 6 chars containing all possible combinations of the 4 chars given in the array?

Comment: Depth 5 and 6 will never be reached unless size of n is 5 or 6, respectively. The depth is limited by two factors, the size of n and MAX_DEPTH.

Comment: @andiroid: You couldn't legitimately call the function with `n` (from `main()`) as an argument if the value for `x` was 5 or 6.  You'd be invoking undefined behaviour.  The change to use `char n[] = "abcd";` is trivial: `int x = strlen(n);` — that would be generally safer (arrays of `char` that aren't null terminated, and hence are not strings, tend to lead to problems).  Adjusting the rest is then straight-forward.

Comment: Soo thank you Stephan Lechner.. I think now I got it.. the only problem was that the if(curDepth < x) condition should be MAX_DEPTH instead of x to fit my purpose..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't understand why using x in the if condition anyway since I liked to have it recursive by the depth lvl not the length of the array..

Comment: Don't use `sizeof` to get the number of elements in an array. Although it works for `char` arrays because each element is one byte, it's a bad habit to get into because it will do the wrong thing on arrays with more than one byte per element. Instead define a `countof` macro with `#define countof( array )  ( sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0]) )` and then use `countof(array)`.

Comment: @andiroid: In your question, you have a 3-character `n` and 3 nested loops.  If you had a 6-character `n` and 3 nested loops, you'd get outputs like `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, `aab`, `aac`, `aad`, `aae`, `aaf`, `ab`, `aba`, `abb`, …, would you not?  And if you had a 6-character `n` and 6 nested loops, you'd get longer strings printed.  What Stephan's provided is a good basis for further experimentation.  You should be able to mould it to do what you need.  In Stephan's code, `curDepth` corresponds to `level - 1` in your comments (zero-based instead of one-based indexing).

Comment: @MichaelGeary thank you for pointing that out.. I will try to avoid those in the future.. and also thanks for providing a macro to show a better solution..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I meant if the user input is 6 and the array contain 3 chars I would like to have a depth lvl 6 nested for loop to get all possible combinations out of the 3 chars.. but I got it by now.. thanks for helping and sorry if I explained it bad.. I didn't use recursion often yet so this problem was kind of mind boggling to me..